# How can I safely merge a nested list in Python by use a unique value?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a nested list (list of list) and I want to merge if id from nested list is duplicates: Like :

```
[
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1 }]}
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]} 
  {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]} 
]
```

So at the final solution should be

```
[
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1 },{'port': 79, 'module': 1 } ]}
  {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]} 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined your original nested list as the `unmerged` variable.
The `merged` variable will contain the output

```
unmerged = 
[
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1 }]},
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]},
  {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]},
]
merged = []

for unmerged_item in unmerged:
    match = next((item for item in merged if item['id'] == unmerged_item['id']), None)
    
    if match:
        match['interfaces'].extend(unmerged_item['interfaces'])
    else:
        merged.append(unmerged_item)
```

The output of the code will be as follows (`merged`):

```
[
    {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1}, {'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}, 
    {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}
]
```

Comment: Woah, the worst-case time complexity of this solution is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to accumulate the interfaces with the same id:

```
data = [
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1 }]},
  {'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]},
  {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1 }]}
]

lookup = {}
for d in data:
    iid = d["id"]
    if iid not in lookup:
        lookup[iid] = []
    lookup[iid].extend(d["interfaces"])

res = [{ "id" : iid, "interfaces" : interfaces } for iid, interfaces in lookup.items()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1}, {'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}, {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}]
```

Alternative solution using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
lookup = defaultdict(list)
for d in data:
    iid = d["id"]
    lookup[iid].extend(d["interfaces"])

res = [{ "id" : iid, "interfaces" : interfaces } for iid, interfaces in lookup.items()]
```

**Special Case** *(the groups are contiguous)*

If, and only if, the dictionaries id are contiguous, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), as below:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

res = []
for iid, vs in groupby(data, key=itemgetter("id")):
    interfaces = chain.from_iterable(v["interfaces"] for v in vs)
    res.append({"id": iid, "interfaces" : list(interfaces) })

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': 2404, 'interfaces': [{'port': 78, 'module': 1}, {'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}, {'id': 1234, 'interfaces': [{'port': 79, 'module': 1}]}]
```

If the groups are not contiguous you could sort your data, but that will make the approach less efficient (O(nlogn) due to the sorting) that the dictionary alternatives O(n).